# Json Parsing process

Tags: android, json

I am trying parsing below json in android with below code but I get a error when I do parsing process,How can I parse it? When I do parsing process I get a error in this step **final JSONObject jsonm_kurulum = jsonm.getJSONObject("GetkurulumByIDResult");**

```
   {

        "GetkurulumByIDResult":{
            "Astron_test":"OK",
            "Note":null,
            "aciklama":"ok",
            "adres":null,
            "bayiID":242,
            "bayi_Adi":null,
            "bayi_kodu":null,
            "descripID":null,
            "descriptionCode":null,
            "durum":"1",
            "form_no":"000008",
            "gsm_no":"5493279096",
            "kurulum_tarihi":"\/Date(1473022800000+0300)\/",
            "muhdendis":"umut",
            "ricon_sn":"9922R1608HH0800087",
            "signal":"17",
            "sira_no":124,
            "yetki":"Gökhan Karolo"
        }

    }
    final JSONObject jsonm = new JSONObject(result);
    Log.i("@Log", "GetInfogiris");
    final JSONObject jsonm_kurulum = jsonm.getJSONObject("GetkurulumByIDResult");
    String jsonm_astron = jsonm_kurulum.getString("Astron_test");
    String jsonm_note = jsonm_kurulum.getString("Note");
    String jsonm_aciklama = jsonm_kurulum.getString("aciklama");
    String jsonm_adres = jsonm_kurulum.getString("adres");
    String jsonm_bayiId = jsonm_kurulum.getString("bayiID");
    String jsonm_bayiAdi = jsonm_kurulum.getString("bayi_Adi");
    String jsonm_kodu = jsonm_kurulum.getString("bayi_kodu");

result = {"GetkurulumByIDResult":{"Astron_test":"OK","Note":null,"aciklama":"ok","adres":null,"bayiID":242,"bayi_Adi":null,"bayi_kodu":null,"descripID":null,"descriptionCode":null,"durum":"1","form_no":"000008","gsm_no":"5493279096","kurulum_tarihi":"\/Date(1473022800000+0300)\/","muhdendis":"umut","ricon_sn":"9922R1608HH0800087","signal":"17","sira_no":124,"yetki":"Gökhan Karolo"
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Please share the error message

Answer (score 1):

To share optimized way of json parsing, I would suggest you to follow below steps:

- Use Gson library (you would not need to parse json response manually but instead it will give you POJO based output and so you would be accessing data using getter and setter methods)
- Use this site to create POJO class from JSON http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void parsing(String Url) {

       private ServiceRequest mRequest;
    mRequest = new ServiceRequest(Activity.this);
    mRequest.makeServiceRequest(Url, Request.Method.POST, jsonParams, new ServiceRequest.ServiceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleteListener(String response) {
            String Sstatus = "";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonm_kurulum = new JSONObject(response);

              String jsonm_astron = jsonm_kurulum.getString("Astron_test");
              String jsonm_note = jsonm_kurulum.getString("Note");
              String jsonm_aciklama = jsonm_kurulum.getString("aciklama");
              String jsonm_adres = jsonm_kurulum.getString("adres");
              String jsonm_bayiId = jsonm_kurulum.getString("bayiID");
              String jsonm_bayiAdi = jsonm_kurulum.getString("bayi_Adi");
              String jsonm_kodu = jsonm_kurulum.getString("bayi_kodu");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorListener() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```